# Do not Encode Euro symbol when using java.net.URLEncoder

Tags: java

is it possible to retain Euro symbol post encoding for example.

```
HttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();

        // set POST method details
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url_p);
  post.setRequestHeader(
            "Content-Type", PostMethod.FORM_URL_ENCODED_CONTENT_TYPE);


String beforeEncoding = "Price is  €100";
String afterEncoding = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(beforeEncoding,UTF-8);
post.setRequestBody(afterEncoding);
httpClient.executeMethod(post);
```

it displays Price+is+%80100

is possible to display Price+is+€100

Comment: du you want to urlencode or do you not want to urlencode? One encode the €, the other does not.

Comment: The Euro symbol is not a valid character in a URL, so it *must* be encoded. What problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you for your reply.  I just updated the post I am using HttpClient and providing the url to it using PostMethod class.  But the data i am sending has the Euro symbol which i have to keep intact. But i am requested to Encode except the Euro symbol.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your reply. I just updated the post with more code, the URL receiving the data is looking for a Euro symbol in the post body and i am sending it %80.  I am excepted to encode but not encode euro symbol.

Comment: The current outcome is the correct one, anything else is just nonsense, and certainly not url-encoded. Stop messing with the standard. How is the receiving site supposed to decode the data afterwards, do they handle the € sign in a special way as well?

Comment: @luk2302 they will be displaying the Euro symbol in the documents.  They are not comfortable looking for %80 and converting it into the Euro symbol. What do you think of the idea of me replacing the %80 with Euro symbol post encoding and sending it.

Comment: *"They are not comfortable"* following the *standard*? Their comfort level doesn't matter. If the POST content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then URL encoding *requires* all non-ASCII characters to be encoded. Learn to live with it, or use a different content type where you can do whatever you want (XML, JSON, custom).

Answer (score 1):

If the communication is using UTF-8 (which is sensible for the € Symbol), you should do:

```
String afterEncoding = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(beforeEncoding, "UTF-8");
String afterEncoding = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(beforeEncoding, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The overloaded [`encode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?java/net/URLEncoder.html) without Encoding is deprecated anyway.

Mind, that `System.out` uses the platform's Encoding: `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` or  `Charset.defaultCharset()`.

---

***After comment***

Or do not encode at all, and set the encoding of the body.

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
post.getParams().setContentCharset("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hi Joop Eggen, thank you for your reply. Thank you for pointing out to use the overloaded method with the encoding mentioned. But still the body will not have the Euro symbol post encoding. I am planning to replace the %80 with the euro symbol post encoding.  As the receiving application is expecting a Euro symbol and not %80.

Comment: In that case the receiving application does not do an URLDecode.decode with UTF-8; but it only decodes `+` to space. I added other code to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, not with `URLEncoder.encode`. If your example is that trivial, you may stick to a simple `String.replace`:

```
    String beforeEncoding = "Price is  €100";
    String afterEncoding = beforeEncoding.replace(' ', '+');
    System.out.println(afterEncoding);
```

Comment: Hi maio290,  thank you for the suggestion for replacing.  Are you suggesting afterEncoding = afterEncoding.replace("%80", "€");

Comment: That's something you could do as well. In your example, you only had whitespaces, and if your string were to contain only them, it would have been sufficient to replace these.

Comment: @Santoshbudhe both are **REALLY** bad ideas. If you do `encode` on your end, the others should simply do `decode`. Replacing single chars by hand is a very bad idea.